# Adding undo function to drawing app

Tags: swift, drawing, undo

I followed a [raywenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87899/make-simple-drawing-app-uikit-swift) on using the UIKit to make a drawing app. I'm now trying to add in the functionality to undo the last stroke. Ideally I would like to undo up to 10ish strokes. I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to go about doing this. I was thinking of creating another ImageView which has only the last stroke and making the `ImageView.image = nil` when the user presses back. In the code from the tutorial there's something similar to this. When the touches end, the newest stroke is merged onto the imageview with all of the old ones at the right opacity. I'm not really sure how I could add this third (and potentially more) imageivews to this code to make it work. Any ideas / a better way to go about this? Code for touchesEnded is below.

**Code**

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        if !swiped {
            // draw a single point
            drawLineFrom(lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
        }

        // Merge tempImageView into mainImageView
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImageView.frame.size)
        mainImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1.0)
        tempImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: opacity)
        mainImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        tempImageView.image = nil
    }
```

Comment: Nice tips here: http://nshipster.com/nsundomanager/

Comment: You probably want to save your drawing data in Core Data, since Core Data has a neat function for undo, redo, and save.

Answer (score 2):

@SpaceShroomies: I found/came up with a great solution..

I used parts from [nsHiptser](http://nshipster.com/nsundomanager), and from the [Raywenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87899/make-simple-drawing-app-uikit-swift).

And here i my solution:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    //undoManager
    let undo: UIImageView = undoManager?.prepareWithInvocationTarget(Temp2Image) as! UIImageView

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(Temp2Image.frame.size)
    Temp2Image.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Temp2Image.frame.size.width, height: Temp2Image.frame.size.height), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1.0)
    TempImage.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: TempImage.frame.size.width, height: TempImage.frame.size.height), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: opacity)
    undo.image = Temp2Image.image
    Temp2Image.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    TempImage.image = nil
}
```

The important thing here is to set, what **UNDO** should go back to I.e. `undo.image = Temp2Image.image` otherwise it will not change "it" back

Comment: BTW. i don't you the `swipe` `bool` but i should work fine anyway

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get an undo function working for one step backwards by having a UIImageView that stores the last stroke before it's added to the rest of the strokes when the next stroke is complete... Would there be something wrong with using the same technique to go backwards 10 steps? I would need 10 UIImageViews... Would that be inefficient / cause crashing? The code is below:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        if !swiped {
            // draw a single point
            drawLineFrom(lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
        }


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImageView.frame.size)
        mainImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1.0)
        undo1.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1.0)
        mainImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        undo1.image = nil

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(undo1.frame.size)
        undo1.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1.0)
        tempImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: opacity)
        undo1.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        tempImageView.image = nil
    }
```

Comment: You are on the wrong path. You need 1 custom view in which you override the draw functions. You keep an array of points or paths that represent your image. Every time you add or subtract from that array, you redraw the view.