# redo does not work (ios swift undoManager, Invocation)

Tags: ios, swift, undo, undo-redo, nsundomanager

Using Swift 3.02 (Xcode 8.2) I refer to an undo-solution described in answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31450475/7448394.

In the code below I use this solution to test both undo and redo of a drawing.
When I press the button for randomDrawing it draws a red line from zero to a random point.
When I press the undo-button this line or the last line disappear.
But when I press the redo-button nothing happens to the imageView.
Obviously the undo is working, I also checked undoManager?.canRedo which changes to true after the undo-action, but why does this redo-action shows no result?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    @IBAction func undoDrawing(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        undoManager?.undo()
    }
    @IBAction func redoDrawing(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        undoManager?.redo()
    }
    @IBAction func randomDrawing(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let undo: UIImageView = undoManager?.prepare(withInvocationTarget: imageView) as! UIImageView

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)
        self.imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.imageView.frame.size.width, height: self.imageView.frame.size.height))

        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))                
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: Int(arc4random_uniform(100) + 100), y: Int(arc4random_uniform(100) + 100)))
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setLineWidth(10.0)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setStrokeColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.strokePath()
            
        undo.image = imageView.image
        self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For good measures, check that your redo-button is correctly set up in Interface Builder, and that it triggers your `redoDraving` method.
2. I had the same issue like you (no redoing happening). [This
   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36492619/5670505) helped me.